# Redirect after ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, redirect

Trying to redirect to a different page once my ajax call is successful. My ajax call works fine but I'm a bit lost on how to get the redirect to work.

```
$(".approve").on("click", function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("ApproveNewUser", "Api/Request")",
                type: "PUT",
                data: {
                    Id: "@ViewBag.Id",
                    FirstName: $(".firstname").val(),
                    MiddleName: $(".middlename").val(),
                    Surname: $(".surname").val(),
                }
             }).done(function (data) {
                toastr.success(data, "Success");
         --->   window.location.href = @Url.Action("HR", "Request");  <---
             }).fail(function (error) {
                displayError(error);
             });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it just has to be a string `'@Url.Action("HR", "Request")';`